# How can I render Reference fields from Contentful in React?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

How can I render data from Contentful's References field types? I am able to query the data in graphql and even use it in react to filter posts on my site with;

```
query TestQuery {
  allContentfulPost {
    edges {
      node {
        categories {
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try render it to be displayed in the page it shows blank divs. I however am able to render all other field types, it's only the References field that's not working.

Reference field data in Contentful:
[image: Reference field data in Contentful:]

Reference field data fetched in graphql:
[image: Reference field data fetched in graphql:]

Simple test code:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/Layout.js"

const TestPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query TestQuery {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            categories {
              title
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <Layout>
      {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
        return (
          <div key={node.slug}>
            {node.categories.title}
            Reference fields should be here but their not 
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default TestPage
```

Reference field data Not rendering in React:
[image: Reference field data Not rendering in React:]

//

**UPDATE:**

I have done some trial and error with the GraphQL Fragments as suggested by Ferran below and I am able to view the data in localhost:8000/___graphql with;

```
query TestQuery {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            categories {
              ... on ContentfulCategory {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

However, the divs rendered are still empty. Do I need to change the path for the data source "{node.categories.title}" in the return function for it to work? Do I maybe need to add something between "node" and "categories" to reference the "... on ContentfulCategory" added in the graphql query? If so, how should I write it? I have tried "{node.oncontentfulcategory.categories.title}" but that hasn't worked. Thanks again

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/Layout.js"

const TestPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query TestQuery {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            categories {
              ... on ContentfulCategory {
                title
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <Layout>
      {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
        return (
          <div key={node.slug}>
            {node.categories.title}
            What path should I now use for the data source in the line above?
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default TestPage
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GraphQL fragments in your queries to access the reference data. You have a poor example in [Gatsby docs (`gatsby-source-contentful`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#notes-on-contentful-content-models)) or in some other [GitHub threads](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11094).

The plugin will infer your schema references and will create the proper nodes, allowing you to use them in your queries to retrieve the needed data. You should make some trials and error in your localhost:8000/___graphql to ensure that your model is properly working, without it it's difficult to guess how the query should look like, but it should be something like this:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query TestQuery {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            categories {
                 title
                 slug
                 __typename
               ...on contentfulCategories{
                 #your category fields
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

Further references/articles:

- https://medium.com/@Zepro/contentful-reference-fields-with-gatsby-js-graphql-9f14ed90bdf9

Comment: Thanks Ferran! I'm still stuck. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Edit your post instead of adding a new answer, please. It's easier than that. The field names and the nesting properties are provided by the `localhost:8000/___graphql` and to access the data, you can just print it in a `console.log` and see what's there.

Comment: Sorry about that.